# applicationId is null. in quickblox android after the app goes to background for long time

Tags: quickblox-android

My clients keeps getting this error randomly specifically when the app run in background for long time and then they try to open it i can not reproduce it . Does the QquickBlox object become null at any stage after it is initialised. This is the crash log.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationId is null. You must call QBSettings.getInstance().init(Context, String, String, String) before using the QuickBlox library.
       at com.quickblox.core.helper.Decorators.requireNonNullInRuntime(Unknown Source)
       at com.quickblox.auth.session.QBSettings.checkInit(Unknown Source)
       at com.quickblox.auth.session.BaseService.createBaseService(Unknown Source)
       at com.quickblox.auth.QBAuth.createSession(Unknown Source)
       at com.quickblox.auth.session.Query.createSessionByParameters(Unknown Source)
       at com.quickblox.auth.session.Query.createSessionIfNeedAsync(Unknown Source)
       at com.quickblox.auth.session.Query.performAsync(Unknown Source)
       at com.eyecura.eyecuraandroid.authHelper.AuthHelper.loginCustomObject(AuthHelper.java:155)
       at com.eyecura.eyecuraandroid.activities.auth.LoginActivity$5.onClick(LoginActivity.java:247)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5210)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20976)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```